# Как реализовать алгоритм сортировки методом простого выбора?

Tags: java, алгоритм, сортировка

Как реализовать алгоритм сортировки методом простого выбора?

Comment: Чтобы мы могли вам помочь вам надо показать что вы уже сделали и показать где имеено и что именно у вас не получается

Answer (score 2):

Есть у меня такой алгоритм. Хе-хе... ;-)

```
package selection_sort;

interface LessThan<T>  {
    boolean less(final T t1, final T t2);
};

public class Main
{
    private static <T> void selectionSort(final T[] array, final LessThan<T> lessThan) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
            int index = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; ++j) {
                if (lessThan.less(array[j], array[index]))
                    index = j;
            }
            if (index != i) {
                final T tmp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[index];
                array[index] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    private static <T> void print(final T[] array) {
        for (final T i : array)
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Integer[] array = {7, 0, -4, 3, 1, -2, 5 };

        print(array);
        selectionSort(array, (t1, t2) -> t1 < t2);
        print(array);
    }
}
```